# if elif when looping thru for loop with stack problem in python

Tags: python, if-statement, stack

the problem is here:

> https://binarysearch.com/problems/Unix-Path-Resolution
>
> Given a Unix `path`, represented as a list of strings, return its resolved version.
>
> In Unix, `".."` means to go to the previous directory and `"."` means to stay on the current directory. By resolving, we mean to evaluate the two symbols so that we get the final directory we're currently in.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - `n ≤ 100,000` where `n` is the length of `path`
>
> **Example 1**
> Input
>
> ```
> path = ["usr", "..", "usr", ".", "local", "bin", "docker"]
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> ["usr", "local", "bin", "docker"]
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> ```
> The input represents "/usr/../usr/./local/bin" which resolves to "/usr/local/bin/docker"
> ```
>
> **Example 2**
> Input
>
> ```
> path = ["bin", "..", ".."]
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> []
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> ```
> The input represents "/bin/../.." which resolves to "/"
> ```

my correct solution:

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, path):
        
        stack = []

        for s in path:
            if s == "..":
                if len(stack)> 0:
                    stack.pop()
            elif s == ".":                   #if "elif" is replaced with "if" - it gives error
                continue
            else:
                stack.append(s)
        print(stack)
        return stack
```

on this test case - ["..","..","..","..","..","..","."], the below code

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, path):
        
        stack = []

        for s in path:
            if s == "..":
                if len(stack)> 0:
                    stack.pop()
            if s == ".":                   # "elif" is replaced with if and gives error
                continue
            else:
                stack.append(s)
        print(stack)
        return stack
```

the expected result is [], but my code gives [".."] - wrong result.

The input is not a string where a for loop can mistake ".." vs "." - 1dot and 2dot.

The input is a list and it should clearly distinguish btw ".." and "." -
so i assumed if/elif is not critical.

why does simple replacing elif with "if" gives wrong result?

Comment: Well, you assumed wrong. In the second code, whenever ``s`` is not equal to ``"."`` you will append it to the stack, even if it's ``".."``. You *could* add a ``continue`` in the ``if s == "..":`` block to get the same behavior as with elif, but IMHO ``elif`` is the better choice and makes it clear that you have multiple cases to check and each one doing something different.

Comment: Lazy and probably too slow would be `return os.path.abspath('/'.join(path)).split("/")`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, thx and the question is testing how to use stack , not about knowing shortest 1liner in python

Comment: @ERJAN nothing in your questions OR under the link https://binarysearch.com/problems/Unix-Path-Resolution limits HOW you solve the task. You _choose_ to use stacks - but htat is not the only way to solve it. From a learning experience using a stack is good. knowing what methods python has that can do stuff is good as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually differences between `if-elif-else` and `if-if-else`.
In simple terms, `if-elif-else` is regarded as "one body" while `if-if-else` is in fact two conditional blocks: `if` and `if-else`.

First we look at the `if-elif-else` version. If `s` is `".."`, it will never reach the code inside `-elif` or `-else`. Sensible.

However for the `if-if-else` version of code, as we said it actually goes through two blocks of if-else logic. If `s` is `".."`, it first goes through the first if statement. Then it proceed to the next if-else block. Since `s` does not equal `"."`, so it proceeeds to the code in the else block, which is I believe not what you want.